# Best way to handle CascadingDropDown selections

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, cascadingdropdown

I have three cascading dropdown list boxes. They are setup country, state and city. When I select the country the state gets populated and when I select a state the city gets populated. This is all working as should. But, when the country has no states but has cities how can I select the city?

So I want to select a country and either select a state or city. Is this possible? Its using a web service that I wrote so it can be changed if need be. 
Please help as I am stumped.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: What is your DB structure?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific behavior you want, you need to associate your city with both a city and the country. Your table structure for the City should be

```
CityId - Int (Primary Key)
CityName - VARCHAR(100)
StateId - Int(NULL) FOREIGN KEY (To Id column of State table)
CountryID - Int(NULL) FOREIGN KEY (To Id column of Country table).
```

So when user change a country from dropdown, You load both states and City data. You can load all Cities from the selected country. If you user selects anything from State dropdown, you can do one more level filter to reduce the items in the City dropdown to have only those which belongs to the selected state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense and I will give it a try.